# How to add a customized pdf report to a zip file for download in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I would like to create a customizable, pdf report that a user can download from a shiny application. However, I would like the pdf to be added to a zip file, with other items to be downloaded. I am following [these](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/generating-reports/) instructions but I can't quite get it right.

Here is a reprex app demonstrating my code so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Data Download Test"),

    # Sidebar with dataset dropdown and download button
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("dataset", "Select Dataset",
                        c("Orange", "OrchardSprays", "PlantGrowth")),

            downloadButton("download", "Download")
        ),

        # Show a table
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("datatable")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  #table output
    output$datatable <- renderTable({
      dataset <- get(input$dataset)
    })

    #download server logic
    output$download <- downloadHandler(

      #name of file
      filename = function() {
        paste0("Dataset_", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
      },

      #content of file
      content = function(file) {
        #set wd to temp directory
        tmpdir <- tempdir()
        setwd(tempdir())

        #MAKING CSV
        # Start a sink file with a CSV extension
        sink("dataset.csv")
        cat('\n')
        cat(paste0("Here is the dataset ", input$dataset, "!"))
        cat('\n')
        cat('\n')

        # Write metrics dataframe to the same sink
        write.csv(dataset <- get(input$dataset), row.names = F)

        # Close the sink
        sink()

        #MAKING PDF REPORT
        #copy file
        tempReport <- file.path(tmpdir, "download_reports/report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(selected_dataset = input$dataset)

        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = "report.pdf",
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))

        # Zip them up
        zip(file, c("dataset.csv", "report.pdf"))
      }
      )

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My .rmd template looks like this:

````
---
title: "Dataset"
output: pdf_document
params:
  selected_dataset: NA
---

```{r}
params$selected_dataset

...etc.
````

The template is located within the shiny app r project file at `download_reports/report.Rmd`. The code works when I am only adding the csv to the zip file, but it gives me the following error when I try to add the pdf report to the zip file

```
Warning in normalizePath(x, winslash = winslash, mustWork = must_work) :
  path[1]="/var/folders/_g/0xs4r4jd6kncwg40b2bp21zm0000gn/T//Rtmpmaqfgy/download_reports/report.Rmd": No such file or directory
Warning: Error in abs_path: The file '/var/folders/_g/0xs4r4jd6kncwg40b2bp21zm0000gn/T//Rtmpmaqfgy/download_reports/report.Rmd' does not exist.
```

I think it has something to do with the file paths and/or the temp working directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `file.copy` fails because it cannot find the `report.Rmd`.  At first I thought the problem was that the first argument of `file.copy` had to add the `download_report` folder.  But things are much worse.  When the working directory gets changed to the temp folder, it becomes difficult to find the original file.

A quick hack to get things working is to use

```
output$download <- downloadHandler(

        #name of file
        filename = function() {
            paste0("Dataset_", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
        },

        #content of file
        content = function(file) {
            # save original wd, you'll need it later
            orig_wd <- getwd()

            #set wd to temp directory
            tmpdir <- tempdir()
            setwd(tmpdir)

            #MAKING CSV
            # Start a sink file with a CSV extension
            sink("dataset.csv")
            cat('\n')
            cat(paste0("Here is the dataset ", input$dataset, "!"))
            cat('\n')
            cat('\n')

            # Write metrics dataframe to the same sink
            write.csv(dataset <- get(input$dataset), row.names = F)

            # Close the sink
            sink()
            #MAKING PDF REPORT
            #copy file

            # temporarily revert working directory so you can find the Rmd
            setwd(orig_wd)
            tempReport <- file.path(tmpdir, "report.Rmd")
            file.copy("download_reports/report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
            setwd(tmpdir)

            # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
            params <- list(selected_dataset = input$dataset)

            # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
            # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
            # from the code in this app).
            rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = "report.pdf",
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))

            # Zip them up
            zip(file, c("dataset.csv", "report.pdf"))

            #restore original wd
            setwd(orig_wd)
        }
    )
```

Here I first capture the original working directory (basically wherever your app.R lives) and then temporarily restore that working directory for the `file.copy`, then I re-revert back for the rendering and zipping.  Also, at the very end I revert to the start working directory to avoid problems in the rest of the app (like if you download a second report).

Really, it's best to avoid changing your working directory at all.  It is far better to use `paste` or some other function to tell `sink`, `file.copy`, `render` and `zip` to use your specified directories.  In particular, `rmarkdown::render` has options `intermediates_dir` and `output_dir` to control where the temporary and final files should go.  Also it has the `knit_root_dir` option that specifies a working directory.

I suggest you use the following:

```
output$download <- downloadHandler(

        #name of file
        filename = function() {
            paste0("Dataset_", Sys.Date(), ".zip")
        },

        #content of file
        content = function(file) {

            tmpdir <- tempdir()
            csv_path <- file.path(tmpdir, "dataset.csv")
            rmd_path <- "download_reports/report.Rmd"

            #MAKING CSV
            # Start a sink file with a CSV extension
            sink(csv_path)
            cat('\n')
            cat(paste0("Here is the dataset ", input$dataset, "!"))
            cat('\n')
            cat('\n')

            # Write metrics dataframe to the same sink
            write.csv(dataset <- get(input$dataset), row.names = F)

            # Close the sink
            sink()

            # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
            params <- list(selected_dataset = input$dataset,
                           dataset_path = csv_path)

            # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
            # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
            # from the code in this app).
            rmarkdown::render(input = rmd_path,
                              output_file = "report.pdf",
                              output_dir = tmpdir,
                              intermediates_dir = tmpdir,
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))

            # Zip them up
            zip::zip(file, file.path(tmpdir, c("dataset.csv", "report.pdf")), mode = "cherry-pick")

        }
    )
```

Please note that I am using the `zip` package because `zip::zip` allows us to use the 'cherry-pick' mode so that we don't have to change our working directory to avoid the absolute folder names appearing in the zip.

Also note that I am passing an absolute file path as a parameter to  the Rmd.  I imagine the Rmd will use the data.  The following Rmd works for me when I knit via the app:

````
---
title: "Dataset"
output: pdf_document
params:
  selected_dataset: mtcars
  dataset_path: /
---

```{r}
params$selected_dataset
params$dataset_path
```.

Here is the data

```{r}
read.table(params$dataset_path, skip = 3, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```.
````

Comment: No problem.  I should add that it's important for the intermediate and final files from `render` to go in the temp folder.  Otherwise you might have problems when you deploy your app, because the Shiny server user might have different file/folder permissions than you as the developer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all the files exists, you can try this schema:

```
output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = 'my.zip',
  content = function(filename) {

      zip_file <- "internal.zip"
      
      list_flies <- c( "a.a", 'b.b', 'etc' )
      
      
      # ## Linux
      # # the following zip method works for me in linux but substitute with whatever method working in your OS 
      # zip_command <<- paste("zip -j", 
      #                       zip_file, 
      #                       paste(list_flies, collapse = " "))
      # 
      # system(zip_command)

      
      ## Windows: 
      zip(zip_file, list_flies )
      
            
      # copy the zip file to the file argument
      file.copy(zip_file, filename) ## here's what you are mainly missing


      # remove all the files created
      try(file.remove(zip_file))
  })
```